# Angular 2 (stable), route with outlet and path = non-empty, not working..!

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

A route with router path as below,

```
{ path: 'lefttoggle', redirectTo: 'lefttoggle', pathMatch: 'full', outlet: 'lefttoggle_name'},
```

in Angular2 is throwing exception:

**Edit:**
**MainCompnent.template.html**

```
<div><a href="/lefttoggle">click to show left</a></div>
<div class="col-md-10" style="top:70;left:-1%;position:relative;">
            <router-outlet name="righttoggle_name"></router-outlet>
              <router-outlet name="lefttoggle_name"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**AppRoutes.ts**

```
    { path: '', component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'lefttoggle', outlet: 'lefttoggle_name', component: LeftToggleComponent},
    { path: 'righttoggle', outlet: 'righttoggle_name', component: RightToggleComponent}
```

**Error produced onClick:**

```
core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'lefttoggle'
```

Comment: If typo is not a problem then tell us where and how do you use it? Show more code.

Comment: Have updated the question with snippets, sorry I don't know plunker world, and new to scripts.. help will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a redirect, but you haven't defined any route with an actual component.

Try this:

`{ path: '', redirectTo: 'lefttoggle', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'lefttoggle' , component: LeftToggleComponent},`

When you open the app, you will be redirected from `''`, to `'lefttoggle'`and there the actual component will load. If you don't want to be redirected from `''` just remove that line.

The important factor here is to define a `component` to be displayed.

Edit:

I see you have added more code.
Still you have defined two routes with the `path: 'lefttoggle'`.

How do you want the router to redirect from `lefttoggle` to `lefttoggle`? You have to define different paths.

Comment: thatnks for the effort, but we have it different for both the route paths.

Comment: How is your redirect any different from the actual route? I don't see it.

Comment: please check the edited question, I have modified the redirectTo, have least consideration on redirection. But have call to components, in which ever is possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent },
{ path: 'lefttoggle', outlet: 'lefttoggle_name', component: LeftToggleComponent},
{ path: 'righttoggle', outlet: 'righttoggle_name', component: RightToggleComponent}
```

Change it to,

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent },
{ path: '', outlet: 'lefttoggle_name', component: LeftToggleComponent},
{ path: '', outlet: 'righttoggle_name', component: RightToggleComponent}
```

I also assume that **MainComponent.html** is **AppComponent's html**.

**Working DEMO ; https://plnkr.co/edit/inHDLkO8qbteUORfjUQl?p=preview**

Comment: sorry @micronyks.. I am looking for { path: 'lefttoggle', outlet: 'lefttoggle_name', component: LeftToggleComponent},

Comment: You can not redirect to two different paths at a same time; So if you say when you redirect to `lefttoggle` then it is possible to load LeftToggleComponent's view into leftoggle-named-outlet.

Comment: I am not redirecting at-all, only trying to render the components when clicked on particular positions of a main page

Comment: That is what I'm saying, your path says when user redirect to `path: 'lefttoggle',` then inject leftToggleCmp's view into outlet:'lefttoggle_name'. By remaining on the same page, you can't do it.